# apt-get git on google compute engine

Tags: git, apt-get, google-compute-engine

I am trying to add git client to my google compute engine debian-7 instance, and I am running into following problem:

```
Err http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates/main libcurl3-gnutls amd64 7.26.0-1+wheezy6
  404  Not Found [IP: 212.211.132.32 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/pool/updates/main/c/curl/libcurl3-gnutls_7.26.0-1+wheezy6_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 212.211.132.32 80]
```

wget to http://security.debian.org works.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you do

```
apt-get update
```

before?

There was a critical bug found in GNUTLS recently, so it might have been updated in the meantime.